# import external static file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I need to include some external css/js files in my webpack project.
Currently I'm doing this which doesn't seems to work.

```
    let inputCss = document.createElement("link");
    inputCss.setAttribute('href', "../../assets/iti/css/intlTelInput.css");
    inputCss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
```

I tried adding the file with absolute path, still it doesn't work.
so just as a work around I'm pasting the link from cdn to make it work, but I need to import that file locally.

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: This code seems to have little to do with webpack, since it happens at runtime. It's likely the path is wrong.

Comment: I'm almost sure that path is correct, how do confirm ?

Comment: Does the file load in the front-end? If it does then the path is correct.

Comment: no, it doesn't load in the browser because of webpack I think, whatever I try, but it exists I verified

Comment: I think this is unrelated to webpack since the code loads the file after webpack has run.